Moving a project from Visual Studio vs VS Code with same git config
A Visual Studio project (.csproj file) is in a subfolder of the solution project (.sln file) so if you transition from using Visual Studio to VS Code and want to use the same git config, you will have to move the .git folder down to the .csproj subfolder which is probably not advisable, is there a better way around this when moving a project from VS to Code?
